# What do the names Pesil, Pesa, and Pesha mean?

Tags: words, names, etymology, yiddish

What is the meaning and source of the name Pesil or Pesa or Pesha?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Pesha is the yiddishized version of Basya.

Answer (score 5):

To corroborate @YDK's comment, it seems to be from Basya (or Bisya):
http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/489777/jewish/What-does-the-name-Pessy-mean.htm

Comment: How does it "seem to be" from Batya? It either is or it isnt...is it? How do you know?

Comment: @AviPesa, welcome to Judaism.SE! Please consider registering your account, which will give you access to more of the site's features, including the ability to respond to questions and answers with comments, like this one.

Comment: @AviPesa you don't know; so you speculate. Welcome to etymology :) In this case, I used "seems" b/c the page I linked to does not present any specific sources.